# Парные и непарные звонкие и глухие согласные звуки

Tags: согласные

Звонкие согласные различаются от глухих тем, что они произносятся с голосом и шумом. Глухие согласные состоят только из шума. Вопрос: как быть, если в упор не различаешь некоторые звонкие и глухие, не можешь по звучанию определить произносится с голосом или только шумом?

Comment: Вы на слух их не различаете или просто не знаете, какая из них произносится с голосом?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте выучить пары наизусть. Первая (если у Вас ведущая звуковая память) или левая (если зрительная) согласная в паре - звонкая: б - п; в - ф; г - к; д - т; ж - ш; з - с; м, н, р, й - звонкие; х, ц, ч, щ - глухие.

Comment: При чем тут выучить наизусть, если у человека, к примеру, проблемы со слухом? Зачем ему это?

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас русский родной (а судя по всему - так) и нормальный слух, то вы должны различать на слух *код* и *кот*, *лес* и *лез* и т. п. в других формах: *кота* и *кода*, *леса* и *лезла*. Есть другой прием. Шепотом говорить умеете? При шепоте все согласные (и гласные, кстати, тоже) произносятся без голоса.

Это я про звуки. Ну а какие буквы им соответствуют, думаю, вы в курсе.

Хотя, признаться, вопрос не очень понятен. Вы на слух их не различаете или просто не знаете, какая из них произносится с голосом? И то и другое несколько странно. Первое может свидетельствовать о каких-то дефектах слуха (хотя я встречал разное, но чтоб такое...), а если второе, то просто какой-то комплекс, просто не задумывались, наверное.